# How to combine multiple rows as one in Bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table which has data as shown below image

[image]

I wish to create a table out of this data which is as shown below image [image]

So here I wish to

1. remove the email column data
2. combine the emp_type column values as comma separated value
3. have just 1 row per id

I tried using STRING_AGG function of BigQuery but was unable to achieve what I specified above.

The table actually has more than 30 columns but for the sake of explaining the issue i reduced it to 7 columns.

How do I combine multiple rows as one in a query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select 
  any_value((select as struct * except(email, emp_type) from unnest([t]))).*,
  string_agg(emp_type, ', ') emp_type
from data t
group by to_json_string((select as struct * except(email, emp_type) from unnest([t])))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

As you can see here - it will work no matter how many columns you have 30+ or 100+ . you done even need to type them at all!

Comment: how can I eliminate the duplicate entries coming as part of string_agg(emp_type, ', ') emp_type ? @MikhailBerlyant

Comment: unless you have `order by` within `string_agg` - you can use `distinct` in `string_agg` - see documentation for details

Answer (score 3):

I see two possible options, if you want to have uniqe row per combination of all parameters except email and emp_type:

```
SELECT id, name, status, `count`, is_hybrid, STRING_AGG(emp_type, ', ')
FROM data
GROUP BY id, name, status, `count`, is_hybrid
```

If you want to have just one row per id, you can group by id and select arbitrary value(from rows with this id) for other columns:

```
SELECT id, ANY_VALUE(name), ANY_VALUE(status), ANY_VALUE(`count`), ANY_VALUE(is_hybrid), STRING_AGG(emp_type, ', ')
FROM data
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question that I have 30+ columns, I was hesitant to use GROUP BY on all the columns. The second query you have given seems apt in my case.

Comment: @GopinathS - can you clarify - you have 30+ columns that you want to exclude (similar to email column) or include into output?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant - I want to include the 30+ columns except the email column

Comment: so, in above two options  - you will need to type either 30+ column names in GROUP BY or 30+ times  `ANY_VALUE(column_name)` + 30+ times respective aliases. right? doesn't seems to me this really addresses your case (while still good answer of course)